# timedatectl set-local-rtc --adjust-system-clock don't change the 3rd line of /etc/adjtime

Tags: centos, time

man page says about set-local-rtc:

> This command will change the 3rd line of /etc/adjtime.

The 3rd line changed when `timedatectl set-local-rtc <true/flase>`.

The 3rd line not changed when `timedatectl set-local-rtc <true/false> --adjust-system-clock`.

CentOS 8.5.2111

systemd 239 (239-51.e18)